# Typing for: Either property "a" is set or property "b" and "c" is set

Tags: typescript

Is there a way for typescript to know that either `this.a` will be set or `this.b` and `this.c` will be set?

Taking the following code, there should never be an instance where all items will be set or none will be set due to how the constructor is setup.

```js
export class MyClass {

  readonly a?: SomeClass
  readonly b?: string
  readonly c?: string

  constructor(a: SomeClass)
  constructor(b: string, c: string)
  constructor(...args: ([SomeClass] | [string, string])) {
    if(args.length === 1) {
      this.a = args[0]
    } else {
      this.b = args[0]
      this.c = args[1]
    }
  }

  echo() {
    if (this.a instanceof SomeClass) {
    } else {
       someFunction(this.b, this.c)
    }
  }

}
```

`someFunction` is giving the following error:

> Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

I know I could do an `else if(typeof this.b === 'string' && typeof this.c === 'string')`, but that seems like a long approach. Is there another way that this could be done?

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GUIFtgDCqGcA3gL4BQokscAZgK4B2CMAlhM3GnsAGIs2nZgAoAbiiQAuHjCjtmAcwA0cSUgBMstPMVKAlBUrVw0eMnSYAsgE8iVsibhwowFABMuSW3BQB+WRx8BwxKFzdPb18AI0C5BWVw13cvZh9EeN1EpWdELmzGNmhRFCC+ULQDZIQC+SKYEpidPWU1BBac6pda5kLiqFEAOhGUKCU0WVEAbWDCYjQAXTgAHzhp7P01TeVFgwMnFxd2elLxtCGkYGUYAAs4AF4nuABGA9Jko7g79guUR7852mAAZFp84OQ4MAkGhgIcvt9br8hjEAWMJiCwQjEciEGigS8sUcqC4qMlgAhbhBRO9wSc4KIfn84IpdChWMAIPRsBUFrSvpDobD4QjePhBKwOFxGUiLjE1EyhghusTkmTyEA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/m0Lgrm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Really you want `MyClass` to be a union type, but classes and interfaces cannot be.  You will have a much easier time if you push any union-like things down into properties like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEDObW) instead of trying to force the compiler to recognize that the class itself is union-like

Comment: @jcalz I have created an example link

Comment: And you're aware that `this.a` will never be a `string`, right?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Either property "a" is set or property "b" and "c" is set

The key concept here is "or". Use a TypeScript union type to achieve it i.e. `{a} | {b,c}`. Here is a complete example:

```
class SomeClass { };

export class MyClass {

    readonly values: { a: SomeClass } | { b: string, c: string }

    constructor(a: SomeClass)
    constructor(b: string, c: string)
    constructor(...args: ([SomeClass] | [string, string])) {
        if (args.length === 1) {
            this.values = { a: args[0] };
        } else {
            this.values = { b: args[0], c: args[1] };
        }
    }

    echo() {
        if ('a' in this.values) {
            const { a } = this.values;
        } else {
            const { b, c } = this.values;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can ignore undefined
if (!this.a) {
    someFunction(this.b!, this.c!)    
}

// or better way: check if strings are assigned
if(this.b && this.c){
    someFunction(this.b, this.c)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/NwKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQGckFsCmAxaeZKACgEMAuDOAJwSgHMAaVAIwvVvoYEoBvECAC+IGABsy6dKgDK2HAGEJU1AOGCcADwAOSGnFTjJ0gLIBPJcdWDUqGjjIATFGLOoyAfipzclqSFt7Jxc3Vi9qOkYAuwdnKFdDcM5IhhtDFGSIeD1yb3k-dB5omAzaLLgc9gjuFhgqZO4i2xKoTOyaEgA6brIaBnQqEgBtH0VldABdVAAfVCGGxhYFhgmeHmtbWwQwcj70TrEcRjgAC1QAXkvUAEZ1gU3N04R9sgv3PaGABgno2yFUHBidA4DYPVBPfasN69fpfH5g8EnZ6dGDQj7XeGbER-NI4GAnJAkO6-VDbVAkACEEM6ZGJCNsmFwBFgiBQJGprApLGpMAp602JOxm227KRkNQADIJYjkTB+CT6Rh5MyiGyOdyxSimljoiJ1CAoDgAO6ocwFEgAckkjnQZAtLAt6BtjgtPCAA)